# Firebase SDK creating ambiguities with Unity's System.threading.Tasks

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I've recently upgraded my Unity project to 2021.2.3f1 on the new M1 16inch macbooks. Upon importing Firebase's SDK, I get the following error on async Tasks types:
[image]

It seems there's an ambiguity happening since it works fine without the SDK. Someone in the Firebase discord suggested that:

> it's most likely related to the plugins folder dll files,
> there should be a some dlls and a folder called net4xx,
> if you remove (zip so you can restore it) the rogue dll files, it may fix it..
> so only the net4x folder remains

Unfortunately the only net-something folder i've got in my project is in Assets>Parse>Plugins> and is called dotNet45, but it's the only one and there isn't any other net4-something folder anywhere in the project. Removing that dotNet45 folder creates lots of errors.

Someone knows what are the steps to fix this pls?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was almost there. They're not folders, its these two files that should be deleted:

[image]

Then it should be fixed !